# Problems with `__str__` method in recursive list type objects

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm trying to make an object which basically a list, but with extra features.  when i use it (such as by printing it)  I want a custom display. for example:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __init__(self, name, arg):
        self.name=name
        super().__init__(arg)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}: {1}".format(self.name,self[:])
if __name__=="__main__":
    B = MyList("george",range(3))
    A = MyList("bernadett",range(5,0,-1))
    B.append(A)
    A.append(B)
    print(B)
```

It prints out `george: [0, 1, 2, [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, [0, 1, 2, [...]]]]`
I would like it to always print the name of the Mylist before going into the list, and I would rather limit the recursion depth to 1, instead it should just print the name and leave it at that.

so I would like something like:  `George: [0, 1, 2, Bernadette: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, George:]]`

also, whenever I try to alter the `__repr__` for the list type object, I get infinite loops and I don't know why.

thanks.

Comment: I think your problem might be format(self.name,self[:]).  self[:] might be causing your program to call the __str__ method of list and not MyList.  After reading what I wrote, it sounds ridiculous.  However, in the off chance that it helps you I wanted to post it anyways

Comment: thanks for the help,  I figured that calling the str of the slice, would call str on each item... so str for the ints for  the first few items, and then str for the last MyList item in the queue, and I figured that would take care of it... but not so much.

Answer (score 2):

Use the parent representation:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "{0}: {1}".format(self.name, super().__repr__())
```

You have to define this as the `__repr__` method, because on lists it is the one used to print the elements inside it.

Doing that, the above code will result in:

```
george: [0, 1, 2, bernadett: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, george: [...]]]
```

Comment: Hey it worked!  thanks.   

Why should I be using repr instead of str here?

also, should I be putting an argument in super()?  super(list) or something?

Comment: you need `__repr__` because that's what the list will call on inner elements. For python 3, you can call `super` without arguments. If the answer helped, you can click the "tick" mark under the vote count.